# How can I print the the created PDF file in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, printing

Okay i am using a FPDF library to generate pdf files

```
    $this->load->library('fpdf');


    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(200,10,'Coupon Information',0,0, 'C');
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'user id: '.$user_id);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'coupon name: '.$name);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'coupon price: '.$price);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'discount: '.$discount);
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'coupon number: '.$gen_id);
    $pdf->Output();
```

how can i make the print of a PDF file instead of the output in php?, or is there a solution for codeigniter?

Answer (score 2):

Printing a PDF is a client-side operation you can't force printing from your code. Imagine, you visit a website and your printer throws paper. That would be... weird!

Comment: @yeahitsme Just show them the PDF. If you want, you can embedded the pdf inside an iframe, so you can show a border at the top, which explains the user should print. Maybe you can also use javascript to trigger the print dialog with `window.print()`

Comment: but what if i use the above code, is there a way to transfer it to javascript?

Comment: Javascript is able to build PDF with third-party library, like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). I am not sure about the result, but you will still not be able to call `window.print()` even if you build PDF with Javascript. Indeed, this method is used to print an HTML document, not a PDF one.